# Android premium App monthly or yearly Subscriptions

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, payment-gateway, subscription

i am making an application in which after few using the application 20 times user will stop at splash screen and show text "Demo version is over" after that a button pop up "Purchase app". After clicking on that button a new page will appear saying monthly or yearly. 

Example:
 if user wants one month subscription then after paying(using any payment gateway) The App will run from current date to next 30 days(One Month). after that same procedure.

what i need is maintaining this 30 days by code from current date in my application. after that 30 days validity is over  showing same text message "Purchase your subscription".

Thanks you.

Comment: Show what you've done your self, read something etc. etc. don't just request a solution.

Comment: do some work and when you have a problem ask it here.

Comment: i have done all the coding of my application. now i want to implement this kind of code where i can maintain app. for the one month example<br/> Like counter with zero when i purchase the one month subscription the counter with set to 30 days after using that application for 30 days it will show message that purchase your subscription if the user purchase it for 1 year the counter will set to 365 days from current date. i want something like that sir I am confuse how to use it. Thanks you

Comment: Instead of using counters, I'd store an expiry date. And just compare that date at the app start. If it's due, then display a Dialog (with only the OK Button) and then finish the app when that button is clicked. EASY.

Comment: Don't do it from the app, app side solution can be easily compromised, also if user clears the data or re-installs the app he/she loses subscription feature, instead save it on the server side. if you are using google in-app purchases it has its own subscription module which you can use directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a counter in sharedPreferences which will increment by 1 on each subsequent launch. Put conditions to check the value of the counter at each app launch and write your logic in it.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

     sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferencesName, 0);

     if(sharedPreferences.getString("firstDate","").equals(null)||sharedPreferences.getString("firstDate","").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
               sharedPreferences.edit().putString("firstDate",getCurrentDate()).commit();
            }else{
                  compareDates()  
            }
    }
```

For comparing the date logic visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_compareto.htm

Comment: yea but counter will run on each launching of application what is need sir is  "Days" like from current date to next 30 days. Thank you

Comment: You can store the date in the sharedPrefereces on the first launch. Then on each subsequent launch compare this date with the first data and accordingly write your logic.

Comment: sir can you provide me that kind of  logic it will be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Something Like This**

> Create this methods to stored required data in shared preferences

```
private void setSubscription() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(SUBSCRIBED, true);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean getSubscription(boolean defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getBoolean(SUBSCRIBED, defaultValue);
}

private String getSubscriptionDate() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getString(SUBSCRIBED_DATE, "");
}

private void setSubscriptionDate(String strDate) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(SUBSCRIBED_DATE, strDate);
    editor.commit();
}

private int getCounter() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getInt(COUNTER, 0);
}

private void setCounter(int count) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(COUNTER, count);
    editor.commit();

}

private void setOneMonthSubscription() {
    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30); // add 30 days

    date = cal.getTime();

    setSubscriptionDate(String.valueOf(date));
}

private void setOneYearSubscription() {
    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 365); // add 365 days

    date = cal.getTime();

    setSubscriptionDate(String.valueOf(date));
}
```

**Try This Logic With OnCreate Of Activity OR As you need it**

```
if(getCounter() == 0) {
        int counter  = getCounter();
        counter++;
        setCounter(counter);

        //this is first time loaded

    } else {

        if(getCounter() >= 20) {

            //reached to 20

            if(getSubscription(false)) {

                Date date;
                //user subscribed
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();

                try {
                    date = dateFormat.parse(getSubscriptionDate());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    date = new Date();
                }

                //Check if Subscription End or not
                if(date.getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
                    //user subscription ends
                    //make counter to 0
                    setCounter(0);
                    //make subscription date to empty
                    setSubscriptionDate("");

                } else {
                    //allow user because subscribed
                }


            } else {

                //means user not subscribed yet show please subscription message

            }
        } else {
            int counter = getCounter();

            counter++;

            setCounter(counter);
            //allow user because it not reached to 20th times

        }

    }
```

**You Need This Members**

```
private final String SUBSCRIBED = "subscribed";
private final String SUBSCRIBED_DATE = "subscribed_date";
private final String COUNTER = "counter";
```

Comment: This is just through and activity. Better solution is to save data at server side because if user uninstall the app then again user will get 20 days to use.

Comment: actually the application is in that manner it can not be all time connected with server... only the time when the user purchase the subscription.

Comment: Ok then above logic make sense.